# How to get Logic App Metrics?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to get Logic Apps metrics like BillableExecutions, Latency etc in my console application.

Currently I'm able to list the logic apps runs, triggers, versions using the .Net Client Microsoft.Azure.Management. But it doesn't seem to have the API to access the monitoring API's.

**Code excerpt**

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var token = GetTokenCredentials();
            var client = new LogicManagementClient(token, new HttpClientHandler())
            {
                SubscriptionId = new AzureSubscription().SubscriptionId
            };

            var dataQuery = new ODataQuery<WorkflowFilter>
            {
                Top = 50
            };

            using (client)
            {
                var logicAppsWorkFlows = client.Workflows.ListBySubscription(dataQuery);

                foreach (var logicAppsWorkFlow in logicAppsWorkFlows)
                {
                    var runs = GetWorkflowRuns(client, logicAppsWorkFlow.Id.Split('/')[4], logicAppsWorkFlow.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine(runs.Count);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(logicAppsWorkFlows.Count());
            }
        }
```

Can someone tell me how to access Logic Apps Metrics? Is there a client similar to Microsoft.Azure.Management for access metrics data?

**Update 2**

I have found a client dll which was in pre release mode which is used to get metrics. Below is my current code

```
var token = GetTokenCredentials();
            var insightsClient = new InsightsClient(token, new HttpClientHandler())
            {
                SubscriptionId = new AzureSubscription().SubscriptionId
            };

            var logicManagementClient = new LogicManagementClient(token, new HttpClientHandler())
            {
                SubscriptionId = new AzureSubscription().SubscriptionId
            };

            var dataQuery = new ODataQuery<WorkflowFilter>
            {
                Top = 50
            };

            using (logicManagementClient)
            {
                var logicAppsWorkFlows = logicManagementClient.Workflows.ListBySubscription(dataQuery);

                foreach (var logicAppsWorkFlow in logicAppsWorkFlows)
                {
                    using (insightsClient)
                    {
                        var metricsDataQuery = new ODataQuery<Metric>
                        {
                            Filter = "name.value eq 'ActionLatency' and startTime ge '2014-07-16'"
                        };

                        IEnumerable<Metric> metricsList = null;
                        try
                        {
                            metricsList = insightsClient.Metrics.List(logicAppsWorkFlow.Id, metricsDataQuery);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e);
                        }


                        if (metricsList == null) continue;
                        foreach (var metric in metricsList)
                        {
                            foreach (var metricValue in metric.Data)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(metric.Name.Value + " = " + metricValue.Total);

                            }
                        }
                    }


                }
            }
```

I'm getting an exception saying the filter string is not valid. Im referring the filter string structure provided here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/filter-syntax

Can someone tell what im doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Yes I have enabled it, Im able to view it in the portal. Im just not able to bring the data to my console application using azure api's

Comment: What is the nuget library and version you are using?

Comment: Im using 0.14.1-preview, Microsoft.Azure.Insights

Comment: Is your error message similar to: {
  "code": "BadRequest",
  "message": "only conditions of the form '<name> eq <value>' are allowed, where <name> = 'timeGrain', 'startTime', 'endTime', 'name.value', 'aggregationType', 'debugRegion' : name.value eq 'ActionLatency' and startTime ge '2016-02-20'"
}

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you got?

Comment: Hi @juvchan Yes I got the same error and ifigured out why it was throwing it please check my answer. thanks for looking into it though

Comment: Have you considered using OMS for this?

Comment: No @DerekLi This is the first time Im hearing about it, I will take a look at it :)

Comment: Give it a try. Under a logic app resource, you should be able to, under the monitoring blade, log to a free OMS instance. Then, within OMS, you can write queries to analyze the data. And if it has all the datapoint you're interested in, you don't have to write or maintain any code but just use the dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like ge is not allowed for Logic Apps StartTime field for some reason. I had to change the code to below to make it work

```
using (logicManagementClient)
            {
                var logicAppsWorkFlows = logicManagementClient.Workflows.ListBySubscription(dataQuery);

                foreach (var logicAppsWorkFlow in logicAppsWorkFlows)
                {
                    using (insightsClient)
                    {
                        var metricsDataQuery = new ODataQuery<Metric>
                        {
                            Filter = "startTime eq " + DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " and name.value eq 'BillableTriggerExecutions' and endTime eq " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                        };


                        var query = metricsDataQuery.GetQueryString();
                        Console.WriteLine(query);
                        IEnumerable<Metric> metricsList = null;
                        try
                        {
                            //throws exception if there is no metrics data
                            //TODO: Check whether the logic app ran atleast one time
                            metricsList = insightsClient.Metrics.List(logicAppsWorkFlow.Id, metricsDataQuery);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e);
                        }
                        if (metricsList == null) continue;
                        foreach (var metric in metricsList)
                        {
                            foreach (var metricValue in metric.Data)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(metric.Name.Value + " = " + metricValue.Total);

                            }
                        }
                    }


                }
            }
```